# Angular (8): Custom-Auth-Module should handle/wrap an external OAuth-Module (by forRoot-import) and provide a wrapper-service for the OAuth-Service

Tags: angular, service, oauth

in our company-internal Angular fired framework, which is used by multiple internal Angular apps, I want to provide a module which should be usable by multiple apps to provide an OAuth-Handle. We want to use the external Angular lib "angular-oauth2-oidc". This lib describes that it should be imported by "forRoot" in AppModule, so its OAuthService can be used for authentication etc. Now I trying to create such wrapping module, but my implementation is failing as whatever I  do, the external OAuthService is not correctly provided, so that my service cannot inject it to work with it.

A quick overview over the current module structure:

```
@NgModule({
imports: [LoginModule],
providers: [],
components: [ App1Component ---> injects+uses LoginService ]})
export class App1Module {}
-----------------------------------
@NgModule({
imports: [LoginModule],
providers: [],
components: [ App2Component ---> injects+uses LoginService ]})
export class App2Module {}
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
@NgModule({
imports: [KeycloakModule, OtherLoginTechniquesModules],
providers: [LoginService ---> injects+uses KeycloakService, OtherAuthServices],})
export class LoginModule {}
---------------------------------------------------------
@NgModule({
imports: [CustomOAuthModule ],
providers: [KeycloakService ---> injects+uses OAuthService],})
export class KeycloakModule {}
---------------------------------------------------------
@NgModule({
imports: [OAuthModule.forRoot()],
providers: [],})
export class CustomOAuthModule {}
```

It works when I import the OAuthModule.forRoot() module in AppModule, but not when is imported in CustomOAuthModule. All Modules are eager-loaded, so not lazy-loaded. 
As far I understand, the importing -and providing chain should be correct or not? What is the problem with my idea?
Thank you very much.

Regards,
Max